# Using LINQ -Concat duplicate records

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Problem: I have a list with lots of data and I don't know how to merge duplicate data into one unit + it should not affect others. If possible, would like everyting to be happened in the same list without creating more list to acheive the result Using LINQ

```
CaseID  ApproverID
1   23
1   45
1   56
2   33
2   90
3   58
3   79
```

in broader sense i want something like caseID 1 with approverID AS `23 ,45,56`

Comment: how data is presented in list ?

Comment: Please show the code you use to get your current result.

Comment: Do you want to join the multiple ApproverID with comma?

Comment: Hi Tim, i want to join multiple ApproverID with Comma associated with unique caseID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to group the records, you can do this

```
var result = source.GroupBy(x => x.CaseID, x => x.ApproverID);
```

The first lambda expression selects the group key. The second lambda expression selects the values. If you ommit the second expression, the source value will be returned. You can use the result like this:

```
foreach (var group in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
    foreach (int value in group) {
        Console.WriteLine("    " + value);
    }
}
```

The result will be

```
1
    23
    45
    56
2
    33
    90
3
    58
    79
```

Answer (score 5):

```
MyData
  .GroupBy(d => d.CaseID)
  .Select(g => new{
                CaseID = g.Key, 
                ApproverIds = g.Select(x => x.ApproverID).ToList()})

  //.Select(x => new{
  //               x.CaseID, 
  //               approverIdsString = string.Join(", ", x.ApproverIds)})
```

Last part is commented out because comma-separated strings of lists are rarely a good idea.

Comment: if both fields are part of the *same* object, yes, this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's called grouping:

```
var groups = myList.GroupBy(element => element.CaseId);
```

You can iterate groups as if each element contained a list:

```
foreach (var g in groups) {
    Console.WriteLine("Case ID:{0}", g.Key);
    foreach (var element in g) {
        Console.WriteLine("Approver ID:{0}", element.ApproverId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To avoid duplicates, use [Enumerable.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx)

Comment: this is not about avoiding duplicates, but about grouping based on some key.